# How can I stop main thread and waiting sub thread in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am using `::WaitForSingleObject(event, INFINITE)` in main thread, and in sub thread I use `::SetEvent(event)` when finish sub thread. But it does not work. I wonder why??

Comment: I wonder too. It depends what exactly your event is, when it has been set (and if it auto resets). Something like that, without more context...

Comment: Thanks for your modify, when I debug it wait in ::Waitforsingleobject(event, INFINITIVE) forever.

Comment: It depends on code around that. How did you create your event? Are you sure SetEvent is even called (or it hangs waiting for something from main thread)? Are you sure you're synchronizing on same object?

Comment: If Waitforsingleobject doesn't return, then the event is not signaled. Please give more context/infos/source code.

Comment: Thanks Adriano and manuell. I had found my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Standard way for waiting a thread exit, is to use `WaitForSingleObject` with the handle of the thread, and doing so reliability involves using [_beginthreadex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx) for creating the thread.

```
HANDLE hThread = reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>( _beginthreadex( ... ) );
if ( hThread ) {
   DWORD dwRet = WaitForSingleObject( hThread, INIFINITE );
   if ( dwRet == WAIT_OBJECT_0 ) {
      // OK
   } else {
      // Error
   }
   CloseHandle( hThread );
} else {
   // Error
}
```

The handle of a thread created with `AfxBeginThread` may be obtained via the `CWinThread::m_hThread` member.

Please not that synchronously blocking on a thread exit may question the idea of creating a thread in the first place.

Please not also that blocking a main thread, especially with an `INFINITE` parameter, seems a very bad idea if that thread has a GUI.

EDIT: you may be able to do a blocking wait, **while processing sent message**. Use the `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` API, with `QS_SENDMESSAGE` as `dwWakeMask`. Note that you will have to check the awakening condition an wait again if that's not the one you wait for.

Comment: Thank you. But in my case, it hang on WaitingForSingleObject( hThread, INFINITE ); Do you have any idea?

Comment: If Waitforsingleobject doesn't return, then the handle you pass is not signaled. Please give more context/infos/source code.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.
When Main thread stand by, in sub thread I call message and send to Main thread. It seem to be DeadLock.